# ghc6 install trouble: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid UTF-8 byte sequence)

Tags: 10.10, apt, package-management

Having trouble installing `ghc6`.

Here's what seems to be the relevant error that comes up when I try to (apt-get|aptitude) install `ghc6`:

```
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up ghc6 (6.12.1-13ubuntu1) ...
ghc-pkg: /home/opm/.ghc/i386-linux-6.12.1/package.conf.d/unix-compat-0.2-edefa7bced91ebe610d455bab466e200.conf: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid UTF-8 byte sequence)
```

(Here's the full output, if you're interested: http://paste.ubuntu.com/566475/ )

This still happens after `apt-get clean` and `apt-get update`.

My searching around has not really helped me understand what's going on, except that it might be caused by a mismatch in locale. So, here's the output of locale too:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Any ideas?

Additional background: this all seems very strange to me, because I used to have `ghc6` installed correctly--I use XMonad as my main window manager most of the time. I tried to install `haskell-platform` (through apt), which failed and told me that there was something wrong with `ghc6`, and so I reinstalled `ghc6` and began to get the above error message.

(Originally posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/245135/ghc6-install-trouble-hgetcontents-invalid-argument-invalid-utf-8-byte-sequence) to SuperUser, until I remembered today that this SE site existed.)

Comment: I was getting same message - "my-prog: fd:6: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)" and running it with LANG=en_US.utf8 helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the output of `ghc-pkg list`. I had the same problem, and in my case it was due to an old `~/.ghc/i386-linux-6.12.1/package.conf.d`. Deleting `~/.ghc` solved the problem for me.

Comment: @olimay Please accept the answer (and vote it up) if it has solved your problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, and your solution fixed it. Thanks a lot!